# SOAP validation in java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have been validating manually SOAP in Postman and need to automate. Not sure how to proceed and what all is needed.

```
request:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <soap:Body> 
    <Getbb xmlns="http://abc/"> 
      <Number>123456</Number> 
      <Id>GUID</Id> 
    </Getbb> 

  </soap:Body> 

</soap:Envelope>

Response:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns01:GetbbResponse xmlns:ns01="http:abc/">
            <GetbbResult>
                <Profiles>
                    <Profile>
                        <AccountName>9999999</AccountName>
                        <Num>123456</Num>
                        <EmployeeId>33333</EmployeeId>
                        <LastName>ddd</LastName>
                        <FirstName>ffff</FirstName>
                        <Title>Eng 2, XOC</Title>
                        <WrkAddress1>1234</WrkAddress1>
                        <WrkAddress2> </WrkAddress2>
                        <WrkCity>water</WrkCity>
                  </Profile>
                </Profiles>
            </GetbbResult>
        </ns01:GetbbResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How to validate the response, if someone can give some direction?

Comment: you're looking for the term XSD Schema

Comment: Sorry, can you please be little elaborate. I haven't done SOAP and need to understand on how.

Comment: XSD schemas are used to define what a valid payload looks like. It's a file, similar to XML. There are Java libraries that then consume that XSD definition to create a validator which you would feed your XML through. An example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xsd/xsd_validation.htm)

Comment: so i need to create a xsd file - based on what i read.
But mine is an api testing to be automated

Comment: You still need to know what valid looks like, so yeah you'll need to create one

Comment: This is an api testing to be automated.
i have a request and response and i need to validate the columns and their value

Comment: is this a safe site to generate the xsd file? https://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html

Comment: I wont be able to answer that for you. I'd suggest learning how to create an XSD yourself, they're not complicated.